# TryGetValue pattern with C# 8 nullable reference types

Tags: c#, nullable

I'm playing with porting some code to C# to enable nullable reference types, and I've encountered some functions in our code that use the `TryGetValue` pattern.

That is, something like this:

```
public bool TryGetSession(string key, out Session session) {
    session = null; // assign default
    // code which looks for a session based on the key, etc
    // return true or false if we found the session key
}
```

The pattern which we're trying to express here is "if the return value is true, then `session` is non-null. If false, then don't even attempt to look at the session, it's garbage.

The problem is I now get a warning on `session = null`, but I'm forced to put *something* there as `out` parameters MUST be populated by the function.

Is there a good answer here? My thoughts:

I could drop the `TryGet` pattern and embrace the nullable reference types (This is what other languages like Swift seem to do) e.g.

```
Session? GetSession(string key);
```

Or, I could live up to my "non-null" promise using a placeholder value e.g.

```
public bool TryGetSession(string key, out Session session) {
    session = new InvalidSession(); // assign default
    ...
}
```

Are there any other options?

Comment: Wouldn't `public bool TryGetSession(string key, out Session? session)` be the appropriate way to express this?  "TryGet" doesn't really make sense if the output parameter has to be non-null.

Comment: AFAIK, this is one of the cases where the !-operator is required to ignore the warnings. I actually designed my methods like `bool TryGetValue(TKey key, TValue? value) ` (since that's what they do), and in the calling code used `value!` after checking the returned boolean, of course. Wish there would be something more intelligent!

Comment: @madreflection `out Session?` would be the best way to express it in the C# type system, however then afterwards I have to explicitly null-check the value, or use `!` - both of which it would be nice not to have to do

Comment: That *is* rather unfortunate. I know it's still an extra step but pattern matching seems relatively idiomatic for the null check and can be done inline: `if (TryGetSession(key, out Session? temp) && temp is Session session)`.

Answer (score 55, accepted):

If you're arriving at this a little late, like me, it turns out the .NET team addressed it through a bunch of parameter attributes like `MaybeNullWhen(returnValue: true)` in the `System.Diagnostics.CodeAnalysis` space which you can use for the try pattern.

Returning a swift-style nullable reference type works well, but the try pattern lets you return things like errors as additional out parameters.

```cs
public bool TryGetSession(string key, [NotNullWhen(returnValue: true)] out Session? session, [NotNullWhen(returnValue: false)] out string? error)
{
  // etc
}


// This is okay:
if(TryGetSession("cheese", out var session, out var error))
{
  var time = session.Time;
}

// But this is not:
_ = TryGetSession("cheese", out var session, out var error);
var time = session.Time;
// "CS8602: Dereference of a potentially null reference"
```

Further details:

- [Documentation about the attributes](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/csharp/nullable-attributes)
- [Language Design Meeting about it](https://github.com/dotnet/csharplang/blob/master/meetings/2019/LDM-2019-05-15.md).

Comment: Does look like it's only for .NET Core, even though you can use this C#8 language feature in .NET 4.8 (only partially supported, officially)

Comment: `NotNullWhenAttribute` is protected... At least in `.NET 6`.

Comment: @l33t, what do you mean by protected?

https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.diagnostics.codeanalysis.notnullwhenattribute?view=net-6.0

Comment: @NickDarvey It could be that the assembly/project I was working on targeted `.NET Standard 2.0`.

Answer (score 5):

I originally ended up going with the swift-style `Session? GetSession()` so the original version of this answer said that.

I later switched to using `[NotNullWhen(returnValue: true)]` as per Nick Darvey's answer. Because of the `out var` feature that C# has (and because C# lacks 'if let'), the `TryGet` pattern ends up being more concise and a better fit.

Note: These attributes only exist in .NET Core 3.0 or greater, they're not in the desktop .NET framework, however you can define them yourself and apply them to your own methods and they work as expected.

Comment: "_however you can define them yourself and apply them to your own methods and they work as expected_" : can you please elaborate on this? I am interested. What field do I need to set in the Attribute?

Comment: or alternatively, where can I found the corresponding source code for .NET Core? I know https://referencesource.microsoft.com, but it's for .NET Framework and I'm lost for .NET Core github repos.

Comment: @Pac0 google for "github dotnet runtime" and you find: https://github.com/dotnet/runtime
Then within that github repo search for "NotNullWhenAttribute" and you find this:
https://github.com/dotnet/runtime/blob/1926a3c7e36c137a996fe1c2a8430866cf32127d/src/libraries/System.Private.CoreLib/src/System/Diagnostics/CodeAnalysis/NullableAttributes.cs

Comment: Just add https://github.com/manuelroemer/Nullable package to get all attributes. Suggest to read https://stu.dev/csharp8-doing-unsupported-things/ .